# control anger with persons

Tags: mental-health, subconscious-stress, violent-behavior

I am human,I have feelings and I can't overcome my anger alone.I have anger in my mind with some persons who went(and maybe will) and make bad things  to me. I didn't do anything yet. I don't know If I will do. Are methods or techniques that could make me from angry to calm my self and to feel relaxed? Especially,if I see a person like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course ! You can control your angry. But instead of controlling it, you can show it in a peaceful way or forget it. I experienced it lot. Before few years, I used to get angry often. Showing your anger towards others should be in a peaceful manner if you want to show your angry. Count numbers in your mind from 1..10 when you get angry.

Try these simple steps:

- Breathe deeply, from your diaphragm. Breathing from your chest won't relax you, so picture your breath coming up from your "gut.
- "Slowly repeat a calming word or phrase, such as "relax" or "take it easy." Keep repeating it to yourself while breathing deeply.
- Use imagery. Visualize a relaxing experience from your memory or your imagination.
- Try non-strenuous, slow exercises. Yoga and similar activities can relax your muscles and calm you down.

Practice these techniques daily. Eventually, you'll be able to use them automatically when you're in a tense situation.

**It's best to find out what it is that triggers your anger, and then to develop strategies to keep those triggers from tipping you over the edge.**

Tips to tame your temper : http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/adult-health/in-depth/anger-management/art-20045434

Reference :  http://www.apa.org/helpcenter/controlling-anger.aspx

http://www.apa.org/topics/anger/control.aspx

Play with Kids :) Smile :) Laugh a lot :) Enjoy Your Life :)

Answer (score 1):

If you desire professional assistance, psychologists have specific training in therapy that can help. A therapist will likely work on developing skills based around becoming aware when you are starting to become angry, and training in techniques to lower your anger levels.